# facebook page tab - client doesn't appear in the drop down list when add page tab

Tags: facebook

I was trying to make a facebook page tab for my client and I following the steps in the following link:

http://blog.hubspot.com/blog/tabid/6307/bid/26330/How-to-Create-Custom-Tabs-for-Facebook-Business-Pages.aspx

---

EDIT: These are the steps:

1. Login in as my developer account
2. Choose "Add New App" -> webpage
3. Input the App Display name and click "Create App ID"
4. Choose "Add platform" in the App Dashboard -> settings, then choose "Page Tab"
5. Input my page content's link in the "Secure Page Tab URL" field - with https
6. Open an browser and type [facebook_URL]/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&next=MY_URL, replace MY_APP_ID with App ID I find in the setting, replace MY_URL with the link in step 5

---

Then I found I am stuck because there is no option I can choose in the "Facebook Pages" List, as shown in the image below:
[image: facebook add page tab]

Then I did 2 more steps:

7. In the Dash board, go to settings and input my contact Email
8. In the Status and Review menu, switch to yes on "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"

Tried again but the facebook owner still no show up in the list

As far as I know the facebook page owner has granted me a administrator right to their page. What else do I need to set or the page owner need to set and didn't mentioned in the above steps?

Comment: instead of the link, please add the steps you did in description

Comment: what do you mean with "facebook owner"? what exactly do you expect to show up in the list? it´s a list of facebook pages you are admin of. make sure you are admin and the page will show up.

Comment: I am the developer of the page tab and requested my client's for the facebook page permission to add this page tab on their facebook. They said they've granted me to be admin, but I couldn't see that. That's why I asked here to make sure 1. I didn't miss something that needs to be done and 2. The possibilites  of this happen - Maybe theres some setting that my clients need to be done, other than accept my permission request?

Comment: If you are an admin of the page, then you should see it under https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/pages – if you don’t, then you are not an admin of the page, and therefor can not add a page tab to it via the dialog. // You could easily send that dialog URL to your client, and have them add the app to their page themselves.